# How to trigger a pop up using qtip

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml, qtip

I have the following qtip code which when a link is clicked produces a popup.  Is there a way using jquery I can extract from the code that the link with id equal to "test2" was clicked or not?

Many thanks,
James

```
<ul>
<li><a id="test1" href="">example 1</a></li>
<li class="PopRequired"><a id="test2" href="">example 2</a></li>
<li><a id="test3" href="">example 3</a></li>
<li><a id="test4" href="">example 4</a></li>
</ul>



$('ul li.PopRequired').each(function () {
    $(this).qtip(
    {
        content: {
            text: '<a href="">example text here',
            title: {
                text: true,
                button: '<img src="/images/close_Icon.gif">'
            }
        },
        position: {
            corner: {
                target: 'rightMiddle',
                tooltip: 'leftMiddle'
            },
            adjust: {
                screen: true
            }
        },
        show: {
            when: 'click',
            solo: true
        },
        hide: 'unfocus',
        style: {
            tip: true,
            border: {
                width: 0,
                radius: 4,
            },
            width: 264,
            height: 195,
            title: { 
                background: '#ffffff'
            },
            lineHeight: '16px'
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place a click handler on your a-tags and easily fetch the ID using

```
 jQuery(this).attr('id')
```

in order to retrieve the attribute value.

However, assigning an ID to all your anchor tags might bring limitations, because it may only occur once.

Perhaps better, you could also store your id/ref using a data- attribute (in your case an ID) along with your element.
It will be stored as data-x attribute.

For instance:

```
 <a href="#" data-uniqueid="ABC">my link</a>
```

the ID ABC you can retrieve using $(this).data('uniqueid'); at the moment someone clicked the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I really get what you want.

I prepared a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/neysor/YCTzb/) collection for you which shows how you can select data in you qtip tooltips. All with the [qTip2 Library](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/)

#### HTML

```
<a id="id1" href="#">Text 1</a>
<a id="id2" href="#">Text 2</a>
<a id="id3" href="#">Text 3</a>
<button data-info="This is">Text 4</button>
<button data-info="with more">Text 5</button>
<button data-info="Information">Text 6</button>
```

#### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').button().qtip({
        content: {
            text: function() {
                return "Text: " + $(this).text() + "<br>ID: " + $(this).attr("id");
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Modal qTip for Links',
                button: true
            }
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click',
            solo: true,
            modal: true
        },
        position: {
            my: 'center', // ...at the center of the viewport
            at: 'center',
            target: $(window)
        },
        hide: false,
        style: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-rounded'
    });
    $('button').button().qtip({
        content: {
            text: function() {
                return $(this).attr("data-info");
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Modal qTip for Buttons',
                button: true
            }
        },
        show: {
            event: 'click',
            solo: true,
            modal: true
        },
        position: {
            my: 'center', // ...at the center of the viewport
            at: 'center',
            target: $(window)
        },
        hide: false,
        style: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-rounded'
    });
```

});​